# .htaccess redirect 301 multiple query

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect a URL with lots of query fields to another file on the same site.
I have tried this code but it does not seem to work

```
 Redirect 301 /details.php?id=500+&price=$3.99&img=/thumbnails/500.jpg&plan=plan3 /500-example
```

Comment: write the uri that you want to redirect and the expected result

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You say it "does not seem to work".  Could you [edit] your question with more information? For example, is there any information in the logs that may be relevant? Have you found anything in the documentation of the Apache web server, that talks about passing query fields in a redirect? If so, please include it in your question. The more we know, the better we can help. Good luck!

Comment: Also... a quick search on "apache redirect and query string" led me to [this](https://serverfault.com/q/500961/158513). I'm not quite sure if this works in your case, but it might give you inspiration. Good luck!